# How to keep program running

Tags: c++

I want my code to keep on running without exiting. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to use an infinite loop to keep it running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    POINT coord;
    GetCursorPos(&coord);
    fstream file;
    file.open("example.txt", ios::out | ios::in);


    // Reding from file
    

    //closing the file
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
    
    GetCursorPos(&coord);
    
    if (MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN) {
        cout << "Coords: " << coord.x << " , " << coord.y << "\n";
            xCoord = coord.x;
            yCoord = coord.y;
            file << xCoord << "," << yCoord << endl;
    }
   

   

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, the idea is to log every left click a user has done and put them in a text file, but it just ends after getting one iteration. Is there a way for it to take more than 1 iteration? I've tried using a for infinite loop, but it just floods the whole file with the same coordinates.

Comment: You need a loop. There's no way to keep your program running without one. Think about it.

Comment: Do an infinite loop `while(1)`, the first instruction would be waiting for a mouse event (blocking), thus the CPU will not jump to 100%...

Comment: Ik its logical to use a infinite loop but it gets stuck in the loop, is there a way to like go in and out of the loop so i can log as much left click as possible?

Comment: 'floods the whole file with the same coordinates.'. Two suggestions: keep the loop, but 1. only log when coordinates change. 2. Only log each k iterations. For example each 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `while(!GetAsyncKeystate(VK_END))` to keep the code running however for this to work as intended you want to also change `if(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)` to `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON )) {`

So your code would now look like

```
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
    GetCursorPos(&coord);
 

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON ) & 1) {
            cout << "Coords: " << coord.x << " , " << coord.y << "\n";
            xCoord = coord.x;
            yCoord = coord.y;
            file << xCoord << "," << yCoord << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When you press the END key on your keyboard your program will stop :3

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, the code would still log hundreds of the same mouse coordinates even if the mouse button is not clicked. Is it possible to have it just log a coordinate the moment the left mouse button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, simply add &1 to` if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON )) {`

it should look like `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON ) &1)  `
This is working for me :] and I updated my original response to include it

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` is a constant value. This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) says the value is `0x0002`.

This means that:

```
if (MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)  // this is always true.
```

So if you add a loop this if condition is always true so it will record a value every iteration of the loop. You need to find a function that returns the state of the mouse button.